# how to produce a delay effect

Tags: jquery, loops, timer, delay

I have a loop with in a loop like this

```
$.each(requiredCities,function(keya,valb){
 $.each(requiredKeyWords,function(keya,valb){
  download(keya,valb);
 });
});
```

I want this download function to be called every 2 seconds.
The problem is im unable to use setTimeout.

Comment: The author hinted that he didn't want to use setInterval in code, but accepted an answer that does just that. It is clear that the issue was not well formulated.

Comment: thank you very much, but if i may restate what i said, "No setInterval isn't helping either".

Comment: Removed the -1 since you clarified it. But I suggest this read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
var i=1;
$.each(requiredCities,function(keya,valb){
 $.each(requiredKeyWords,function(keya,valb){
    var timerId = setInterval(function(){
       download(keya,valb);
       clearInterval(timerId);
    }, 2000*(i++));    
 });
});
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Use the `delay` method from the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) if you want to waits some time before next call.

Use `everyTime` method from [jQuery Timer Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers) if you want your code runing again continuously after some time (I think it's your case based on your comment).

Comment: But it says that .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects, so how do I use delay in this case

Answer (score 0):

I find that creating a simple function and calling your code through the function via setInterval instead of setTimeout. It really just depends on what you are trying to do.

perhaps this would work better:

```
setInterval("fooBar()", 1000);

function fooBar(){
$.each(requiredCities,function(keya,valb){
 $.each(requiredKeyWords,function(keya,valb){
  download(keya,valb);
 });
});
}
```

not sure if that works, but at first brush I think it would be fine